# Hide symlink and permission status in nautilus thumbnail view

Tags: nautilus

[image: Nautilus thumbnail]

I use git annex to backup my pictures, which results in more than half of the image telling me it's a symlink and I don't have write permissions. I'd rather just hide. It doesn't seem like dconfig has anything visible to change.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the icons (found via strace)

```bsh
gimp /usr/share/icons/Yaru/{8x8,16x16,24x24,48x48,256x256}/emblems/emblem-readonly.png
inkscape /usr/share/icons/Humanity/emblems/48/emblem-symbolic-link.svg
```